# When to use Heat of Products - Heat of reactants and Heat of reactants - Heat of products when calculating enthalpy change

Tags: thermodynamics

In my schoolbook there are multiple questions where I have to calculate the enthalpy of formation, heat of reaction, enthalpy of reaction, etc etc. But sometimes the formula to be used is Hp - Hr, and sometimes it is Hr-Hp. **So, when do I use what?**

**(Hr = Heat of reactants
Hp = Heat of products)**

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Please find guidance for MathJaX / $\LaTeX$ as follows and reformat your post - [Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) // [MathJaX and mhchem formatting for equations and chemical formulae](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) // [Guidelines on which should be upright / italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: Also you can refer this guide on [how to use MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It's not clear without some examples.